# Django Rest Framework - Create object with foregin key relation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I created simple REST API which i want to create product objects. My problem is that API view is not showing me multiple choice field to choose from existing categories.

models.py

```
from django.db import models 

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default="")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product, Category


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Product, Category
from .serilaizers import ProductSerializer, CategorySerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    

class CategoryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

That is what i get after running server, only two positions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`__all__` does not work with `ForeignKey` and other relationship fields. You need to specify the field names explicitly. Add a list or tuple with field names to your `ProductSerializer`.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ("name", "price", "category")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't worked, output is still same